# Searching in a .map file with C

Tags: c, string, compare

i want to create a tool which is able to search for a specific word in a .map file.

The word i am searchin for is ".text". I have loaded the file with
input_file = fopen("file_location","r") in read mode.

Now i am trying to search in this file for the string .text. My file has over 200 lines.

I would really appreciate some help from your side to solve this problem, because if(input_file == ".text") is not working.

my next solution would be to check every line for a match, but i dont know how i can load a complete line of a file into an array ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Proceed in steps. Firstly I would search "c read entire line from file" ? Google is a huge help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fgets()` to read the whole line and see whether your word is there in that line using `strstr()` perform the same operation till you read the whole file.

```
char buf[100];
while(fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),input_file) != NULL)
{
   if(strstr(buf,".text"))
      printf("Word found in the file\n");
}
```

Comment: You might use [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) instead of `fgets` to deal with long lines.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes agree then no need to worry about the length of the line. Anyways let OP get the logic behind this and implement it they way he/she wants

Comment: All due respect, but I would downvote your answer, as it is non educational. This question appears frequently on this site, and the owner of the question should learn how to use this site and in general how to approach complex problems.

Comment: @Sanandrea I have not just given out the answer but have explained what happends by doing this which is educational